# Sql Server - Get SUM() of values for only Active Users

Tags: sql-server, join, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a requirement where i need to get Total Active Employees and Total Sales by RegionId

My query result should be like below.

```
RegionId | TotalEmployees | TotalSales | Average
   1            10            100         10
   2             3             15          5
```

My front end application will pass all the RegionIds as a single string separated by a comma, my query parameter is of type VARCHAR() and the Input paramter will look like '1,2,3,4,7,14,26' and there can be upto 20 Region Ids in a single string separated by a comma.

```
SELECT E.[RegionId] as RegionId
      ,COUNT(E.[EmployeeId) AS TotalEmployees
      ,(SELECT SUM([Sale])
        FROM dbo.[Sales]
        WHERE RegionId = R.[RegionId]
       ) AS TotalSales
      ,TotalSales/TotalEmployees AS Average
FROM dbo.[Employee]
JOIN [dbo].[ufn_StringSplit](@RegionIdCollection, ',') RegionId
    ON E.RegionId = CAST(RegionId.[Data] AS Varchar(5000))
WHERE E.[Active] = 1
GROUP BY E.[RegionId]
```

My Employee table structures look alike below

```
EmployeeId | Name | RegionId | Active
    100      Tom      2          1
    101      Jim      4          0
    103      Ben      2          1
```

Sales Table

```
 SaleId | EmployeeId| RegionId |   Sale
  1         100           2         3500
  2         101           4         2000
  3         100           2         1500
```

Now my issue is when i am getting TotalSales the below query gets all the sales by RegionId, but i need to get All the sales done by only current Active employees in the Employee table

```
(SELECT SUM([Sale])
 FROM dbo.[Sales]
 WHERE RegionId = R.[RegionId]
) AS TotalSales
```

Comment: I am assuming you have an `EmployeeId` column in your `Sales` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to use a sub-select to find the `sum` of `sales` here, that will result in running that query for each and every row.  You want to aproach this in a set based way which means you need to `join` and `group` appropriately:

```
with s as
(
    select e.RegionId
          ,e.EmployeeId
          ,sum(s.Sale) as EmployeeSales
    from dbo.ufn_StringSplit(@RegionIdCollection, ',') as r
        join dbo.Employee as e
            on r.RegionId = CAST(r.[Data] AS varchar(20)) -- Do you really need 5000 characters here?
        left join dbo.Sales as s
            on r.RegionId = s.RegionId
                and e.EmployeeId = s.EmployeeId
    where e.Active = 1
    group by e.RegionId
            ,e.EmployeeId
)
select s.RegionId
      ,count(s.EmployeeId) as TotalEmployees
      ,sum(s.EmployeeSales) as TotalSales
      ,sum(s.EmployeeSales)/count(s.EmployeeId) as Average
from s
group by s.RegionId
```

Comment: Hello Dave, Tried your query, The TotalSales value is now perfect but the TotalEmployees count has messed up, with the query i posted in my question the total active TotalEmployees value was perfect

Comment: @claudia *"Count has messed up"* - Please be specific; I cannot help you if you don't tell me what is wrong.  Looking at the query I am assuming that is is now too high?